# AngularJS (1.4) Argument x is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm following a pluralsight course by Miguel Castro, in it he uses the concept of separate sub applications (in Angular) within an MVC application.

I'm getting the following error but the functions and all seem to work OK.
I have created a cut-down version of the code to show whats going on..

http://embed.plnkr.co/VqSPkAOzpOW0q95F8LH0/preview

Can anyone suggest how to resolve the error.

**Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ControllerNumber2' is not a function, got undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerNumber2 as cn2">
```

inside the element with `ng-app="appMain"`. So angular tries to find a controller named `ControllerNumber2` inside appMain, and it can't find it.

You can have several angular apps in a single page, but they can't be nested into each other. See http://plnkr.co/edit/juzeZRy7WmKaCg0dHrlA?p=preview for a non-nested version of your code, which doesn't throw the same exception.

Comment: first thanks for taking the time to prove the answer and the working code. i guess they have to be nested though as I'm using MVC too. so the appMain will potentially have to wrap the sub applications, the sub applications will be rendered in different views.

Comment: Also, is the error actually causing an issue? its obviously not great to have an error but its not causing any issues.

Comment: Bot apps will step on each other's toes to handle the same piece of DOM. Just don't do that. There's no reason. Just use one app, as angular is meant to be used.